# Image gets bigger than I want it to html

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS, and I am also quite a newbie, just so that's said.

I am making a website, and I have made a horizontal navigation bar at the top with links to other pages on the site, and an icon as well.

When I watch my website in the browser and check the elements with the inspector tool, the list element "li.nav_bar_icon" becomes 80x82.55, and the logo was 64 pixels, got 8+8pixels from padding, 
**BUT WHY IS IT 82.55 ONE THE OTHER SIDE???** WHERE DID THE EXTRA 2.55 PIXELS CAME FROM?

The code for the navigation bar looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav_bar_icon"><img class="icon" src="img/icon.png" alt="Icon"></li>
    <li><a class="nav_bar_button" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_bar_button" href="apps.html">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_bar_button" href="images.html">Images</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.nav_bar ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #00000f;
}

.nav_bar li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_bar_icon {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.icon {
  height: 52px; 
}

.nav_bar_button {
  display: block;
  color: #008CFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Probably because of subpixel rendering: what is the natural width and height of the element? Since you set the icon to a height of 52px, the width will be adjusted based on the aspect ratio and you might end up with subpixel width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because of browser defaults,that is margins..try setting them to 0
Check out on this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't provided a width for your icon image, only a height, so the browser tries to resize it to look well with the given height, you need just to add a width to your image to prevent that, you said it's 64 then 
change your code like this:

```css
.icon {
  height: 52px; 
  width: 64px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting height and width at the same time is a bad idea as it changes the proportion.

Instead try using, max-height or max-width properties.

If you use height, make width as auto and if you use width, make height as auto.

The extra pixels are because it is trying to occupy the whole available space. You can restrict them with max-height or max-width depending on the image size.